# Is there a way to change a function visibility modifier to private (hide it) in derived class in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, inheritance, access-modifiers

For instance, I'm making a custom adapter `UnitsAdapter` class in Android app and inheriting it from `ListAdapter` abstract class that has a public function of `submitList`.

I've made my own function

```
private var unfilteredList = listOf<*Something*>()


fun modifyList(list: List<BattleUnit>) {
        unfilteredList = list
        submitList(list)
}
```

and I want to allow use only `modifyList` outside of this class while make `submitList` usable only inside of it. Is it possible to somehow hide `submitList` function?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  Your `UnitsAdapter` is at the same time a `ListAdapter` and can be used as the latter. For this reason it is not possible to decrease the member visibility.

Comment: This is an example of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): because the subclass can be used anywhere the superclass is, it has to support everything the superclass can do.